# Installing XenServer 6.5 but does not boot up

Tags: xenserver

I have a server with two CPUs, 64GB of RAM and a 8TB RAID 1 drive. I have successfully installed XenServer many times. But when it tries to boot for the first time, it does not boot to the new install.

I have tried the following:

- Made sure UEFI is set to Legacy
- Made sure the Virtual Drive is set as the boot drive on the RAID controller
- I have tried to disable GPT through constants.py file and through menu.c32.

Still it will not boot. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the error message.

Comment: - STANDARD ERROR:
Loading /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz <br/> - STANDARD ERROR:
/sbin/e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock. <br/> - STANDARD ERROR:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: It is much better to edit the original question to include new content than post it in comments (readability).

Comment: Have you tried to use a smaller disk/raid for xenserver installation and add the 8TB raid as a local datastore afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the RAID Controller is not supported. MegaRAID 9271-4i. I installed to a USB Drive and it worked. I am not sure if there is a work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

If a filesystem error happens with a fresh install, it looks like you have a serious hard disk problem. Your disk(s) likely need to be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Legacy DOS partition tables are those used before GPT, they are limited to 2TB.

To try installing with a DOS partition table boot the installer and at the prompt type

> menu.c32

press tab and add

> disable-gpt

to the kernel command line, i.e. before

> --- /install.img

and again run the boot steps as usual.After installing you should be able to boot